# mySQL Sub Select needed

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have three tables, libraryitems, copies and loans.

A libraryitem *hasMany* copies, and a copy *hasMany* loans.

I'm trying to get the *latest* loan entry for a copy only; The query below returns *all* loans for a given copy.

```
SELECT 
libraryitems.title,
copies.id, 
copies.qruuid,
loans.id AS loanid, 
loans.status, 
loans.byname, 
loans.byemail, 
loans.createdAt 
FROM copies 
INNER JOIN libraryitems ON copies.libraryitemid = libraryitems.id AND libraryitems.deletedAt IS NULL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN loans ON copies.id = loans.copyid 
WHERE copies.libraryitemid = 1 
ORDER BY copies.id ASC, loans.createdAt DESC
```

I know there needs to be a sub select of some description in here, but struggling to get the correct syntax. How do I only return the latest, i.e MAX(loans.createdAt) row for each distinct copy? Just using group by copies.id returns the earliest, rather than latest entry.

Image example below:
[image]

Comment: (As Mohsen has demonstrated) A subquery isn't strictly necesssary - but it does tend to be faster!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the subquery , getting maximum created time for a loan i.e. latest entry and joining back with loans to get other details.

```
SELECT 
T.title,
T.id, 
T.qruuid,
loans.id AS loanid, 
loans.status, 
loans.byname, 
loans.byemail, 
loans.createdAt 
FROM
(
   SELECT C.id, C.qruuid, L.title, MAX(LN.createdAt) as maxCreatedTime
   FROM Copies C
   INNER JOIN libraryitems L ON C.libraryitemid = L.id 
   AND L.deletedAt IS NULL
   LEFT OUTER JOIN loans LN ON C.id = LN.copyid
   GROUP BY C.id, C.qruuid, L.title) T
 JOIN loans ON T.id = loans.copyid 
AND T.maxCreatedTime = loans.createdAt
```

Comment: I get [Err] 1146 - Table 'qweylibrary.ln' doesn't exist with this one?

Comment: @Neokoenig, alias name was missed on select for one column, can you try now?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much - was doing my head in :)

Answer (score 1):

A self left join on loans table will give you latest loan of a copy, you may `join` the query to the other tables to fetch the desired output.

```
select * from loans A
left outer join loans B 
on A.copyid = B.copyid and A.createdAt < B.createdAt 
where B.createdAt  is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your query with one simple modification -- table aliases to make it clearer.

```
SELECT li.title, c.id, c.qruuid,
       l.id AS loanid, l.status, l.byname, l.byemail, l.createdAt 
FROM copies c INNER JOIN
     libraryitems li
     ON c.libraryitemid = li.id AND
        li.deletedAt IS NULL LEFT JOIN
     loans l
     ON c.id = l.copyid 
WHERE c.libraryitemid = 1 
ORDER BY c.id ASC, l.createdAt DESC ;
```

With this as a beginning let's think about what you need.  You want the load with the latest `createdAt` date for each `c.id`.  You can get this information with a subquery:

```
select l.copyid, max(createdAt)
from loans
group by l.copyId
```

Now, you just need to join this information back in:

```
SELECT li.title, c.id, c.qruuid,
       l.id AS loanid, l.status, l.byname, l.byemail, l.createdAt 
FROM copies c INNER JOIN
     libraryitems li
     ON c.libraryitemid = li.id AND
        li.deletedAt IS NULL LEFT JOIN
     loans l
     ON c.id = l.copyid  LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT l.copyid, max(l.createdAt) as maxca
      FROM loans
      GROUP BY l.copyid
     ) lmax
     ON l.copyId = lmax.copyId and l.createdAt = lmax.maxca
WHERE c.libraryitemid = 1 
ORDER BY c.id ASC, l.createdAt DESC ;
```

This should give you the most recent record.  And, the use of `left join` should keep all copies, even those that have never been leant.